# Django Celery. How to make tasks execute at the appropriate different times given in variables

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, django-celery

I try to make a task that will be done at a certain time. Example:
A customer borrowed a book on 01/01/2023 15:00 so the tasks will do exactly one week from now if he doesn't return it and charge a fee.
How to make it do at certain different times.

I'm trying to use django celery with rabbitmq, but I'm not succeeding in making this task open at different times only schematically e.g. every 60 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check Celery beat for your case https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

In general, what you can do is create:

1. a task to check your DB instances every 60 minutes and check if you have any upcoming notifications in the next hour.
2. if you have, trigger a celery task to notify the user when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out periodic tasks with celery: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Just create a task that will be executed every minute or every five minutes and check if a charge should be applied and apply it to all objects.